# Installing npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-init

Is there a way to install Gulp globally without access to the network? I have the nuget package installed but don't know how to achieve the same effect of running `npm install --global Gulp` with this.

Do I even need to run this? Or adding the nuget to the project alone is suppossed to be enough?

I'm a real beginner, any help or explain will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `npm link gulp`?

Comment: What is that? I have node.js installed on my pc, and all the needes nugets, but dont have access to the network. How do I integrage Gulp in my project that way?

Comment: What is OS on your PC?

Comment: We have some issues with Window or Ubuntu versions, I need your OS to find a solution.

Comment: My os is windows 7